# some better way to find out and change an object from an array using its attribute

Tags: javascript, for-loop, react-native

Suppose I have an array(`Accounts[]`) of objects whose class is defined as:

```
export const AccountSchema = {
    name: ACCOUNT_SCHEMA,
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'int',    // primary key
        name: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        type: 'string',
        balance: 'int',
        note:'string',
        creationDate: 'date',
    }
};
```

Now for example, I know an account name `Salary AC` and I want to change `balance` of this account.

For example, I want something like below code in JavaScript (some better or the best way).

In below code using `==`means `equality` & `:` means `assignment`

```
for(var i=0; i<Accounts.length; i++) {
   if (Accounts[i].name == 'Salary AC') {
      Accounts[i].balance: 500;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try access by key OBJECT[name].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#find` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))

`Accounts.find(item => item.name === 'Salary AC').balance = 500`

Keep in mind that `find` will always return the first element that satisfies the condition, so it wouldn't be an option if you have multiple accounts with the same name. In that case, use `array#filter` and loop over the returned array.